# How to merge 2 data frames in R to look like this

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

How do I get data frame C from data frames A and B?

Data frame C:

```
Type CountA CountB
A    40     40
B    50
C    35
D           20
```

data frame A:

```
Type Count 
A    40 
B    50 
C    35
```

data frame B:

```
Type Count
A    40
D    20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merge(a, b, all = TRUE, by = "Type")
```

If you wanted the naming you showed,

```
setNames(merge(a, b, all = TRUE, by = "Type"), c("Type", "CountA", "CountB"))
```

Note you'll get `NA` for missing values. Having an empty value would require you to coerce them into strings.

```
merged <- setNames(merge(a, b, all = TRUE, by = "Type"), c("Type", "CountA", "CountB"))
ccol <- c("CountA", "CountB")
merged[ccol] <- lapply(merged[ccol], function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- ""
  x
})
```

Comment: thank you. When I call A i see the values with "column names" but when I merge A and B these disappear. When I call colnames(A) I get "Error in dn[[2L]] : subscript out of bounds." So, how would I get my "header" values into a vector?

Comment: I think I understand: my data is not in the right format to begin with...this is why merge() is not working as expected. I need to get my data into Type and Count columns first...I had assumed they were like this from looking at it. Still learning...

Comment: Did you read your data using `read.table` or similar? Did you specify `header = TRUE`?

Comment: The original dataset has colnames but I ran a group sum using tapply. The result from tapply lost the colnames.

Comment: @val can you show the output of `dput(a)` and `dput(b)` in your question please?